# Ionic 2 only for website

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is this a good practice to build a website with ionic 2 and angular 2. I have to develop a website that look like native mobile app with material design, mobile app component. If i develop only on angular 2 is that as easy as ionic 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to "develop a website that looks like native mobile app" then I would stick with Ionic. Ionic project can be viewed using a normal browser (it's a website that gets packaged up as an app using built-in Cordova tools - if that's what you want). Ionic comes with many UI components that look like native.

Please note, if you are planning to use Ionic to produce purely a website, when navigating between "pages", the url doesn't change. This is understandable since Ionic is really meant to build mobile apps using web technologies and in apps you don't usually use urls to navigate between "pages". So this might make it a bit difficult for a website when trying to deep link to a page. Anyway, Ionic team working towards dealing with this issue and mentioned it in their most recent beta update, see here http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-2-beta-11/ (scroll down to 'URL Support' heading)

Comment: Will that work properly on all the browsers i.e HTML 5 supported browsers

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is not meant for desktop browsers, see supported browsers: 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support

Comment: Where does it say that?